# React + d3.js reading in data but not displaying chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, d3.js

There are a few questions out there like this, but none that answer my specific question. I'm new to React.

I'm creating a beeswarm chart in d3.js and save it as a React component. The underlying data comes from a public Google sheet. Here's the code for the component:

```
// import module styles
import './Beeswarm.module.css'

// React imports
import {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  React
} from 'react'

// D3 imports
import {
  mean,
  max,
  csv,
  scaleLinear,
  select,
  axisBottom,
  forceCollide,
  forceSimulation,
  forceX,
  forceY
} from 'd3'

// Moment.js imports
import { duration } from 'moment' // https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

// import range
import { range } from '../utils'

// declare variables at the top
const timesUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/xxx?gid=0&single=true&output=csv'

const width = 600
const height = window.innerWidth < 768 ? 600: 400
const margin = { top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 20, left: 5 }
const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom
const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right
const circleRadius = 5

// beeswarm component
function Beeswarm () {
  const [timesData, setTimesData] = useState(null)
  const chartRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {

    //trying to use async
    const fetchData = async () => {
      // load data
      csv(timesUrl).then(data => {
        // transform data...
        data = data.filter(d => d > 0)
        setTimesData([...data])
        console.log("Data loaded:\n", timesData)  
    })
    }
    
    fetchData().catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    });
  }, [])

  // if data is still loading, return a div that says that
  if (!timesData) {
    return (<div className="data-loading">Loading in data...</div>)
  }

  // create the x scale
  const xScale = scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, max(timesData)])
    .range([0, innerWidth])

  const svg = select(chartRef.current)
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', innerWidth)
    .attr('height', innerHeight)

  // how many minutes do we have here?
  const minutes = Math.floor(max(timesData) / (60 * 1000))
  const avgTime = duration(mean(timesData) / (60 * 1000), 'minutes')
  const avgTimeAsStr = avgTime.minutes() + ':' + avgTime.seconds()

  // create the concept of the x-axis
  const xAxis = axisBottom(xScale)
    .tickValues(range(1, minutes).map(d => d * 60 * 1000))
    .tickSize(-innerHeight)
    .tickFormat(d => ((d / 60) / 1000) + ' min')

  // add x axis
  svg.append('g')
    .call(xAxis)
    .call(g => g.select('.domain').remove())
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (innerHeight - 20) + ')')

  // set up simulation
  const simulation = forceSimulation()
    .force('collide', forceCollide(d => circleRadius + 1))
    .force('x', forceX(d => xScale(d)).strength(10))
    .force('y', forceY(1).strength(10))

  // draw dots
  const dots = svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + innerHeight / 2 + ')')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(timesData)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', d => {
      return xScale(d)
    })
    .attr('cy', innerHeight / 2)
    .attr('r', circleRadius)
    .attr('fill', "#999999")

  // simulate dots moving
  simulation.nodes(timesData)
    .on('tick', () => {
      dots
        .attr('cx', d => d.x)
        .attr('cy', d => d.y)
    })

  return <>
    <h4>The length of the array is <code>{timesData.length}</code></h4>
    <svg ref={chartRef} width={innerWidth} height={innerHeight} />
  </>

}

export default Beeswarm
```

When the page loads, I initially see the "Data is loading..." paragraph, and then it quickly disappears and shows the h4 tag and an empty SVG. The h4 tag correctly shows the number of items in the CSV, so I know the data has been read in.

Strangely, when I make a small change to the code (even changing the color of the dots), the chart renders and now appears, so I know the d3.js code works too.

**How do I make the chart show up with the title on load?** Right now it only shows up when I make a change to the code. I think this has something to do with the useEffect and ref, but I'm not sure what to change. Thanks in advance!